# Required jars for elephant-bird-pig-JsonLoader()

Tags: hadoop, elephantbird

Which all jars do I need to register to use the elephant-bird-pig-JsonLoader function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple json as well.

```
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-4.10.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.10.jar
REGISTER elephant-bird-core-4.10.jar
```

After this the following command will work

```
MY_JSON = LOAD 'myfile.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');
```

Answer (score 1):

i am pointing some jars.

REGISTER  'elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

REGISTER  'elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';

REGISTER  'elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';